# Vertical alignment of nested itemized lists in tabular

Tags: tables, enumitem, booktabs, adjustbox

Why are A1, B1, and C1 not aligned?   Shouldn't `p` align them on top?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\title{test}
\author{Me}
\date{July 2018}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{P{0.65\textwidth}P{0.65\textwidth}P{0.65\textwidth}}
    \toprule
    A & B & C\\
    \bottomrule

    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item A1
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item A2
            \item A3
            \item A4
            \item A5
            \item A6
        \end{itemize}
        \item A7
        \item A8
        \item A9
        \item A10
        \item A11
        \item A12
        \item A13
    \end{itemize}

    &

    \begin{itemize}
        \item B1
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item B2
            \item B3
            \item B4
            \item B5
        \end{itemize}
        \item B6
        \item B7
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item B8
            \item B9
            \item B10
            \item B11
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

    & 

    \begin{itemize}
        \item C1
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item C2
            \item C3
            \item C4
            \item C5
            \item C6
            \item C7
        \end{itemize}
        \item C8
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item C9
            \item C10
            \item C11
        \end{itemize}
        \item C12
        \item C13
    \end{itemize} \\
    \bottomrule

  \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On my machine the alignment is correct using your MWE.

Comment: hummm .. I'm using sharelatex

Comment: changing the compiler in sharelatex doesn't seem to help

Comment: You should not use `\bottomrule` after the table header, but `\midrule` (not the real problem, I guess). Can you include a `\listfiles` and post the output?

Comment: not familiar with`\listfiles` where does the output end up going?

Comment: In the log-file and the console output. The corresponding section of the log should start with `*File List*`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aforsythe/9ba0907909346993742c1c9168cadbd7

Comment: Many packages you use (including `adjustbox`) are not up-to-date.

Comment: Can’t help that when using sharelatex

Comment: But that explains the alignment difference.

Comment: Really?  Just out of date packages?

Comment: That's the only difference (as far as I can see) between my system and sharelatex (don't know for sure, have no clue about sharelatex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `adjustbox` for tables, as this yields inconsistent font sizes. Better use  `tabularx` to have a table with a fixed total width. Here is a solution to your problem, and some improvements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{test}
\author{Me}
\date{July 2018}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\compress}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\compress}X}}
    \toprule
    A & B & C\\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
        \item A1
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item A2
            \item A3
            \item A4
            \item A5
            \item A6
        \end{itemize}
        \item A7
        \item A8
        \item A9
        \item A10
        \item A11
        \item A12
        \item A13
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item B1
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item B2
            \item B3
            \item B4
            \item B5
        \end{itemize}
        \item B6
        \item B7
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item B8
            \item B9
            \item B10
            \item B11
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item C1
        \begin{itemize}[wide =0pt, leftmargin=*]
            \item C2
            \item C3
            \item C4
            \item C5
            \item C6
            \item C7
        \end{itemize}
        \item C8
        \begin{itemize}[wide =0pt, leftmargin=*]
            \item C9
            \item C10
            \item C11
        \end{itemize}
        \item C12
        \item C13
    \end{itemize} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My compiler times out on this.

Comment: With this very code, and nothing else?

Comment: yes ... appears to be the `[heavyrulewidth]' option

Comment: Oops! Sorry, it was a bad copy-paste. It should be  `\heavyrulewidth`, with a backslash ( it's the thickness of \toprule s and \bottomrule s (fixed). I replaced your inner `\bottomrule`, beccause it doesn't hacve any vertical padding below it, and inserted a `\midrule` withthe same thickness to ensure a correct padding. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: This seems to be on the right track.  You don't appear to still be using the new definition of `P` though.  Is that line needed?  Overall it's a bit larger than I wanted but alignment seems good.  The thing I liked about `tabular` with `p` and the `adjustbox` was that it allowed me to change the size of the text by modifying the width of p.  How can I make the text a touch smaller to avoid long lines wrapping?

Comment: to be clear and I shirk the text I'd like to shrink the vertical space the table occupies slightly as well.

Comment: You can use a fontsize directive, say `\small` or `\footnotesize`. You also can play  with`\tabcolsep`: it's 6pt by default, so between two columns you have 12pt. You may safely go down to 3 pt (so 2×3pt between consecutive columns). As to the vertical space, you can use the `[nosep]` option in the optional arguments of the lists (or set it with `\setlist[itemize]{nosep} ` at the beginning of the table).