# Undefined control sequence in table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to build a table using `tabularx` but I'm get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<template> ...centering \arraybackslash \compress 
                                              \ignorespaces
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this?

Here's my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[default,osf]{sourceserifpro}
\usepackage{booktabs}%For tables
\usepackage{enumitem}%For lists
\usepackage{tabularx}%For tables

\begin{document}

% Table
\begin{table*}[t]
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=3pt, itemsep=1pt, label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,1]{itemindent=12pt, topsep=0pt}
\setlist[itemize,2]{itemindent=30pt, topsep=0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\compress}X}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Disease modeling} & \textbf{Drug Screening} & \textbf{Personalized Medicine}\\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Metastasis modeling
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Invasion/intravasation
            \item Survival/dormancy
            \item Extravasation
            \item Metastatic niche
            \item Epithelial-mesenchymal transition
        \end{itemize}
        \item Tumor heterogeneity/evolution
        \item Mechanical forces
        \item Tumor-ECM interactions
        \item Tumor-stromal interactions
        \item Organ-specific microenvironments
        \item Immuno-oncology studies
        \item Species-specific models
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item PK-PD modeling
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Absorption
            \item Distribution
            \item Metabolism
            \item Excretion
        \end{itemize}
        \item Toxicity
        \item High-throughput designs
        \item Efficacy testing
        \item Novel compound validation
        \item Tumor resistance/sensitivity
        \item Mechanistic studies
    \end{itemize}
    & 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Incorporation of primary cells
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Induced pluripotent stem (iPS) cells
            \item Adult tissue resident stem cells
            \item Biopsy-, blood- or tissue-derived cells
            \item Cancer stem cells
            \item Patient-derived organoids
            \item Genetically modified cells
        \end{itemize}
        \item Integration with Big Data
        \begin{itemize}
            \item `Omics' signatures/readouts
            \item Genome wide association studies (GWAS)
            \item Computational modeling
        \end{itemize}
        \item Biomarker discovery/validation
        \item Individualized trials-on-chip
        \item Tailored clinical management
    \end{itemize} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\caption{Applications of Tumor Chip Technology}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\compress` isn't defined by latex or by any package that comes to mind, what do you want it to do, where did you see it documented?

Comment: Try adding `\makeatletter\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}\makeatother` to your preamble. This `\compress` command seems to be a thing here in TeX.SX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442442/134574 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489185/134574 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114287/134574...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik searching the site for answers again? It'll never catch on:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle At least you can't say I didn't try ;-)

Comment: It is a command which is used to remove the vertical spacing added to a list in a tabular cell.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik that's it ... super helpful.  I'd originally built this code some time back an swiped it from that old document.  The reference you denoted did the trick!  It was in my old document but not in my new one.  My real problem was trying to parse the error log to figure out what exactly was the offending code bit.

Comment: Why not use `\setlist[itemize,1]{itemindent=12pt, topsep=0pt, before=\vspace{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}` to remove the space above and below the listing?

Comment: @agf1997 If TeX tells you `Undefined control sequence`, the undefined command is always the one at the end of the first line of error which, in this case, is the `\compress`, which Bernard just explained.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  Thanks.  Seems obvious in retrospect.  I usually associate `Undefined control sequence` with a package not being loaded so I was trying to find the missing one.

Comment: @leandriis that certainly seems more direct ... not sure about the pros and cons but I'll experiment with that.